# When to take into account a subset's permutation

Tags: combinatorics

Although this question had been asked many times before, I will use it as an example for my question.

Q: We have $m$ ones and $n$ zeros, where $m > n$. How many different ways of ordering them in a string without having any consecutive ones.

My answer: First we choose where to put the ones, which is $\binom{m+1}{n}$. Now we order the zeros and ones: $m! \cdot n!$

But the correct answer is just: $\binom{m+1}{n}$

My question: Why did we not take into consideration the ordering of the $0$ or the $1$?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You say: "First we choose where to put the ones, which is $\binom{m+1}{n}$". But then surely isn't this the answer to the question, namely "How many different ways of ordering them in a string without having any consecutive ones." What I mean is, if you're correct, you've already placed the $1$'s and there's no more to be done as the $0$'s fill in the remaining places automatically.

Comment: I do not understand the answer. For $m=2$ ones and $n=1$ zero, there is only one place to put the zero whereas $\binom{3}{1}$ = 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the permutations of the $0$'s and $1$'s in any given combination. As far as a combintion is concerned ${\color{red}{0}}{\color{black}{1}}{\color{blue}{0}}$ is the same as ${\color{blue}{0}}{\color{black}{1}}{\color{red}{0}}$. That means you don't need to label each $0$ and $1$ *individually* and multiply by the number of the permutations each of the sets of $0$'s and $1$'s would make once you have calculated the correct number of combinations.